# Why are so many real ales so sweet

Tags: taste

When I go to a pub now the choice of real ales seems to be between "bitters" that are in fact very sweet  (e.g. London Pride, TT Landlord etc), or very hoppy beers. When I was a lad you could get bitter that tasted bitter, e.g. Youngs or Boddingtons but these types of genuinely bitter beers seems very hard to find nowadays.   Can anybody recommend where I can get a list of less sweet beers, that I could use to make more discerning selection ?    Many thanks

Comment: The main reason for this change is that more people prefer the sweeter or hoppy ales. They sell more so brewers make more. The good thing is that there are still plenty of bitters - they are a large minority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitters have evolved a lot over time with different brewery trying out a load of different recipes if you have some time and a keen sense of taste try taking a small notepad and pen and start a little journal of beers and give them a score that way you will be able to pinpoint bitters that you enjoy (there are also many apps on the app store that allow you to do this digitally).

As for a list of bitters there is a [Top rated beers](https://untappd.com/beer/top_rated?type_id=192&country_id=41) site you can use to have a look at what is available, this site can be helpful as it has a small description of the beer so you will be able to steer toward the bitters you find appealing instead of a more sweeter bitter

for extra help I have linked directly to the bitters from England section but you can alter the search to suit your needs.